# Export tracklog from GPS information panel

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, tracklog

When I use QGIS on the field, I always turn the tracklog on in the "GPS information" panel. So the tracklog is showed as I walk with the GPS on, but I can't find the way to download this track into a shapefile or a GPX file.

Can someone explain me how to proceed?

Comment: What GPS unit are you using? it might have that info stored on the unit?